# too long string error received Error 414

Tags: wcf

I am facing some problem in WCF Restful web service .

I have an Image and I am sending it to database from Android Application 1st converting Image into base64 string with 10,000 characters through Application.

In wcf reconvert base64 string in to real image and then send image into Db. 
The issue is that when I am sending base64 long character string to WCF. WCF reject it and too long string error received Error 414.

I already used Post and Get both methods and also increase buffer size but same error all time received.

Same method when I apply in .asmx soap web service their each image insert successfully

Comment: Did you already [activate tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get more detailed errors? Can you show us your web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your service buffer setting in binding configuration.If you are working with default one then update it.